# Android : Click notification to launch activity

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

How can one differentiate the `Notifications` and pass them to different activities?
In the below method the third `parameter(String tag`) value is retreived from `onMessage()` that contains a value.
According to that value i wanted to differentiate which URL to open e.g Google or Facebook.
The app terminates after i include the intent code in the "if" conditions below.
Please Help

```
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message,
        String tag) {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Log.d("GCM", "Tag Value " + tag);

        if (tag.equals("one")) {
            // pass to a different activity
                       notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));

        }

        if (tag.equals("two")) {
            // pass to a different activity
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
        }


    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

Comment: in java, you compare strings with .equals, not ==. In your case, you notificationIntent object is null (which you would have known if you had taken the time to read the stacktrace.) (trivial issue which you would have seen had you simply ran your app in debug mode with a couple of breakpoints)

Comment: All that you said is fine thanks i edited. Any update to the answer to the question how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Manifest create intent filter for activities,that you need launch like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.TabsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.dittoadvertising.push" >
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
```

when 
Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com")  = action name in filter

and in your activities will be called method onNewIntent(Intent newIntent), then intent incoming

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like :

```
  if (tag.equals("one")) {
     notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
  } else if (tag.equals("two")) {
     notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
  }
```